# Changing a Crystal Report datasource (access) at runtime in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, crystal-reports

I'm getting the error 'Log on failed' when trying to change my datasource at runtime. I've trawled SO and the SAP site and from that put together the code below, but I'm still getting the error. My access db is 2013 and isn't password protected and I'm using the default "Admin" user. The report has an OLE DB connection. My code loops through all tables, including subreports and changes the login, and I also change the database login. Any help much appreciated:

```
public void RunTestReport()
    {
        DataSet testDataSet = new DL.NonConformance().GetNonConformances(1, "NonConformance");

        var rpt = new ReportDocument();
        rpt.Load(@"C:\Reports\rptTest.rpt");

        SetCrystalLogin(rpt);

        rpt.SetDataSource(testDataSet);

        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;
        crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
    }

    public void SetCrystalLogin(ReportDocument oRpt)
    {
        ConnectionInfo oConnectInfo = new ConnectionInfo();

        string dbpath = string.Concat(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), @"\db\dbacc.db");

        oConnectInfo.ServerName = dbpath;
        oConnectInfo.DatabaseName = string.Empty;
        oConnectInfo.UserID = "Admin";
        oConnectInfo.Password = string.Empty;

        // Set the logon credentials for all tables
        SetCrystalTablesLogin(oConnectInfo, oRpt.Database.Tables);

        // Check for subreports
        foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Section oSection in oRpt.ReportDefinition.Sections)
        {
            foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportObject oRptObj in oSection.ReportObjects)
            {
                if (oRptObj.Kind == CrystalDecisions.Shared.ReportObjectKind.SubreportObject)
                {
                    // This is a subreport so set the logon credentials for this report's tables
                    CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.SubreportObject oSubRptObj = oRptObj as CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.SubreportObject;

                    // Open the subreport
                    CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument oSubRpt = oSubRptObj.OpenSubreport(oSubRptObj.SubreportName);

                    SetCrystalTablesLogin(oConnectInfo, oSubRpt.Database.Tables);
                }
            }
        }

        oRpt.Refresh();

        oRpt.SetDatabaseLogon("Admin", string.Empty, dbpath, string.Empty, true);

        oRpt.VerifyDatabase();

        oRpt.Refresh();
    }

    private void SetCrystalTablesLogin(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ConnectionInfo oConnectInfo, Tables oTables)
    {
        foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table oTable in oTables)
        {
            CrystalDecisions.Shared.TableLogOnInfo oLogonInfo = oTable.LogOnInfo;
            oLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo = oConnectInfo;

            oTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(oLogonInfo);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you can't configure a .accdb datasource at runtime, I'll need to create an ODBC connection.